# Текст сдвигает блок

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, как сделать, чтоб текст блока .users не отодвигал блок .guests

```css
.total {text-align:center;float:left}
#tnum {background:#fff;border:3px solid#222;border-radius:50px;padding: 9px 14px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;width:30px}
.users {text-align:center;float:left}
#unum {background:#fff;border:3px solid #008000;border-radius:50px;padding: 9px 14px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;width:30px}
.guests {text-align:center;float:left}
#gnum {background:#fff;border:3px solid #d6d6d6;border-radius:50px;padding: 9px 14px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;width:30px}
.total, .users, .guests {margin:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="total">
  <div id="tnum">20</div>
  Всего
</div> 
<div class="users">
  <div id="unum">10</div>
  Пользователи
</div>
<div class="guests">
  <div id="gnum">10</div>
  Гости 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в двух случаях круг определяет ширину плавающего блока и текст центрируется, а в среднем текст шире блока, он как бы отцентрирован (но занимает всю ширину), а вот блок над ним не является текстом и равняется по левому краю. Проблему решает `margin:auto`, но лучше переписать код следующим образом:

```css
.item {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.num {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#tnum { border-color: #222;    }
#unum { border-color: #008000; }
#gnum { border-color: #d6d6d6; }
```

```html
<div class="item total">
  <div id="tnum" class="num">20</div>
  Всего
</div> 
<div class="item users">
  <div id="unum" class="num">10</div>
  Пользователи
</div>
<div class="item guests">
  <div id="gnum" class="num">10</div>
  Гости 
</div>
```